# Use neo4j cypher to find most connected nodes that meet given criteria for connection. eg. authors who co-author books

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can anyone help with this odd twist on an otherwise standard query...

Say I have a collection of books, each has a relation to their respective authors.

I want to find the authors who have collaborated the most (and the books on which they have collaborated), where the count of collaborations excludes authors who are only connected to one book.

eg.

- Author1 has authored 3 books (book A, B, C and D) and would therefore
  be eligible to be counted as a co-author. Note book A is solo
  authored by author 1
- Author2 has only one book(book b) and would therefore not be eligible to be counted as a co-author.
- Author 3 has authored 2 books (book b & c) and can be counted.
- Author 4 has authored 2 books (book C & D) and can be counted.

The result on the query above should be.

- Author 1 - co-authorship count 2
- Author 3 - co-authorship count 1
- Author 4 - co-authorship count 1
- Book  B
- Book  c
- Book  D

Note:

- Author 2 would be ineligble (only co-authored a single book)
- Book A would be ineligble (there is only one author)

I can easily return a list of books and authors where there is more than 2 authors on book, but I am having trouble keeping either books or authors with only a single connection out of the result.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Where is the code you have made?

Comment: Hmm. Most of the counts in your question appear to be wrong. Didn't `Author1` author 4 books (with 3 being collaborations)? And are you deliberately subtracting 1 from every co-authorship count?

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH (c:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(:Book) 
WITH c, COUNT(r) as bookCount
WHERE bookCount > 1 
WITH COLLECT(c) as validAuthors
MATCH (a1:Author)-[:AUTHORED]->(b:Book)<-[:AUTHORED]-(a2:Author)
WHERE a2 IN validAuthors AND a1 in validAuthors
RETURN a1.name as author, COUNT(DISTINCT b) as coAuthoredBookCount ORDER BY coAuthoredBookCount DESC`

edit: a1 and a2 in validAuthors

Comment: You may want to make sure a1 is also in validAuthors, otherwise you may get incorrect results. Though if you `UNWIND validAuthors AS a1` before the second MATCH, that would also work.

Comment: The suggestions work  in  relation to restricting books to ones that are co-authored,  but are still allowing authors with  only a  single co-authored book to be  included in the result set.  

I  attempted to code as per comment below

Comment: MATCH (c:Author)-[r:AUTHORED]->(:Book) <-[r:AUTHORED]-(c1:Author)
where c <> c1
WITH c, COUNT(r) as bookCount
WHERE bookCount > 1 
WITH COLLECT(c) as validAuthors

MATCH (a1:Author)-[:AUTHORED]->(b:Book)<-[:AUTHORED]-(a2:Author)
WHERE a1 IN validAuthors AND a2 IN validAuthors AND a1 <> a2
RETURN a1.name as author, COUNT(DISTINCT b) as coAuthoredBookCount ORDER BY coAuthoredBookCount DESC

This is  still permitting  authors who are only  connected to one book in the final result set to appear.  They should all be  connected to at least 2 books in the  results.

Comment: hi @MarkFallu , you are using variable for 'r' for two relations that is incorrect and you need to do COUNT(DISTINCT r) in first aggregation..because same relation can be counted twice if the book has three authors and thrice if book has four authors and so on